# Upload plugins in Wordpress running on IIS7

Tags: wordpress, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a problem when trying to manually upload a new plugin in wordpress.
Uploading media is working perfectly, and also automatically install plugins work as it should, but manually uploading plugins generate an error message:

`The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/11.`

I have checked permissions on `wp-content` and `uploads` and it is set to `Everyone`. I do not think there is anything wrong with permissions since I can upload images, and I see them inside my uploads folder.

I think there might be a problem with the slashes beeing incorrect, does anyone else have this problem?

I'm using IIS7, Windows Server 2008 and Wordpress 3.0.1. Everything is installed with Microsoft Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is way late in answering, but I hope someone may find it useful.

This is most likely a problem with the settings involving the temporary upload location.

Here is what I did to solve a similar problem:

1. Ensure that you are editing the correct initialization file.  Putting:

   in a test.php file and executing it from your web browser will get you the setting.

Look for the setting for "Loaded Configuration File"

1. In that configuration file search for (or add if missing) the following setting:
   upload_tmp_dir = "c:\inetpub\temp\uploads"
2. Ensure that c:\inetpub\temp\uploads exists and is writeable by everyone.  You can tighten this up with specifying the IUSR account if you wish.
3. Recycle/Restart the IIS worker process.  Your choice here as there are a number of ways to accomplish this.

I found a good bit of this info by referring to c:\tmp\php_errors.txt.  The fastcgi.logging should be enabled by default on windows installations.

Comment: Thanks, this is as close to a solution as anyone has gotten, so I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanna add a solution to the good Harold's answer for PHP.

Despite changing the setting "upload_tmp_dir",  I was still getting the same error message *The uploaded file could not be moved to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Wordpress/wp-content/uploads*.

So i have changed also the setting "upload_max_filesize"

> **upload_max_filesize=16M**
>
> *(16M or greater depending on the wordpress's themes size file)*

Hope it helps someone who was stuck like me.

Answer (score 0):

With Filezilla

directory uploads>2010>11 to set permision 777